# how to debug python script with R subprocceses

Tags: python, r, debugging

I am trying to debug this Python code which calls subprocesses in both R and Python. How can I step through this without print statements? Normally it'd be easy but I don't see how to step into the R code if it's being called by a Python script.

Thoughts?

Thanks!